# List of separable verbs (Infinitiv+Verb)

Tags: resource, separable-verb

I am looking for a list of “trennbare Verben” just like the following ones (with Infinitiv+Verb): *sitzenbleiben, fallenlassen, kennenlernen, spazierengehen*

Anything goes as long as it fits the infinitive+verb scheme.

Answer (score 1):

It would be far beyond the scope of this site to provide a list of all separable infinitive to verb compounds.

Online dictionaries will sometimes provide such lists.

A list with at present 59 separable verb-to-verb compounds from *bestehenbleiben* to *wissenlassen* is maintained by [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/index_en.html):

canoo.net: [List of infinitive to verb compounds](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?service=wordformationRules&matchRules=(RWFRule%20Infinitive+V)&wordFormationClass=Infinitive+Verb&entryClass=Cat%20V)

All those verbs follow the scheme infinitve + verb form and usually are separable.

Comment: The link to the list is not permanent and has already stopped working for me. I get a list of all words instead.

Comment: @chirlu: thank you for pointing: is the link (after my edit) better?

Comment: Seems to be working.

Comment: The contents or at least the essence of that link should be moved into the post. I smell linkrot, even with the fixed link.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: it was on purpose that I did not copy & paste the list to here. We do not want to encourage such big-list questions.

Comment: @Takkat that's a good policy, but it also means, that your answer is quite meat-free, if you catch my drift. If the link dies, this thread becomes worthless.

Comment: @Takkat It’s really not that big a list.

Comment: @Crissov: I am not a friend of questions asking for list-answers how  short or how big they might be. They are discouraged network-wide and we should not start to introduce this by providing lists in answers.

Comment: @Takkat It’s a closed set with current rules, so “too broad” doesn’t cover it, and neither does “off topic”. It seems the OP was actually just looking for §34 (4) and, specifically,  §34 E7, but wasn’t aware it’s actually something that has been put in a rule.

Answer (score 0):

[Deutsche Rechtschreibung – Regeln
und Wörterverzeichnis (entsprechend den Empfehlungen des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160928154855/http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de:80/download/empfehlungen2010.pdf):

> **B Getrennt- und Zusammenschreibung**
> (…)
> **§ 34** Partikeln, Adjektive, Substantive oder **Verben können als Verbzusatz mit Verben trennbare Zusammensetzungen bilden**. Man schreibt sie nur in den Infinitiven, den Partizipien sowie im Nebensatz bei Endstellung des Verbs zusammen.
>
> Dies betrifft (…)
> **(4)** Verbindungen mit einem verbalen ersten Bestandteil.
> Verbindungen aus zwei Verben werden getrennt geschrieben (…)
> **E7**: Bei Verbindungen mit *bleiben* und *lassen* als zweitem Bestandteil ist bei übertragener Bedeutung auch Zusammenschreibung möglich. Dasselbe gilt für *kennen lernen*: (…)

There are actually very few verb-verb compounds whose infinitive is written as one word according to recent orthographic rules. It’s only valid (and not required) if the combined meaning is opaque, i.e. the first, left-hand part is used in a figurative sense or the combined meaning is not transparent at all and therefore must be learned. It’s usually literal meaning if you can form a semantically compatible statement without the second part. That basically just leaves *+bleiben* und *+lassen* as right-hand parts.

> - *Ich will dich nicht **hängenlassen**.* ‘I don’t want to abandon you.’
> - *Ich will dich nicht **hängen lassen**.* ‘I don’t want to let them hang you.’ → *Ich will nicht, dass man dich hängt.*
> - *Ich will nicht schon wieder **hängenbleiben**.* ‘I don’t want to repeat class again.’
> - *Das Bild wird bei mir nicht **hängenbleiben**.* ‘I won’t remember this picture.’
> - *Das Bild soll nicht an der Wand **hängen bleiben**.* ‘The picture shall not stay hanging on the wall.’ → *Das Bild hängt an der Wand.*

There is another one, *+lernen*, that is debatable. It differs from the other two in that it often originally did or still may use a *zu* in front of its left-hand partners, e.g. *kennen+*, *lieben+* and *schätzen+*, when separated. You’ll be fine always splitting those.

[Canoo’s 59-word list](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?service=wordformationRules&matchRules=(RWFRule%20Infinitive+V)) from @Takkat’s answer contains 10 duplicates because they have two entries, one for the literal meaning (hence outdated spelling) and one for a conventionalized figurative meaning: *haften+, hängen+, kleben+, liegen+, stecken+, stehen+bleiben* and *hängen+, liegen+, stecken+, stehen+lassen*.

The rest, with just one entry, for *+bleiben* and *+lassen* is
*bestehen+, sitzen+bleiben*
and
*bestehen+, bieten+, bleiben+, blicken+, fahren+, fallen+, gehen+, kommen+, laufen+, platzen+, ruhen+, sausen+, schießen+, schleifen+, schmoren+, schwimmen+, sein+, setzen+, sitzen+, spielen+, sprechen+, springen+, steigen+, sterben+, treiben+, vermissen+, wissen+lassen*.

Some of the other entries are never used figuratively, some (almost) always.
All entries for *spazieren+* followed by another verb of movement (*+fahren, +führen, +gehen, +reiten*) are always split nowadays – *spazieren* is often used as an adverbial verb if you will, but can also be used on its and then implies walking (*gehen*).
The other two entries for *+gehen*, i.e. *flötengehen* ‘go down the drain’ and *stiftengehen* ‘run off’, don’t relate to *flöten* ‘(play the) flute’ and *stiften* ‘donate; create’, respectively, in any obvious way, so they should be written as one word except when – rarely – used in a literal sense, but according to official rules they are now split always. Go figure.

One entry doesn’t actually follow the alleged INF+INF pattern and is inseparable: *sonnenbaden*. There is a reflexive verb *sonnen* which basically means the same as *sonnenbaden* ‘sun-bathe’, but it’s not used to form the compound which instead is based directly upon *Sonne* ‘sun’.

PS: This has been a major point of criticism by professional writers when the orthography reform was publicly discussed in the second part of the 1990s, and still is. PEN authors etc. would have preferred a general rule that favored writing as one word whenever the compound meaning was not literal, regardless of the types of the components. As you can see, it’s more relevant to adjective+verb compounds etc. – *kennen lernen* was the only change that was really disliked, hence its exceptional inclusion later on.