# »Einen Parameter durchschleifen«

Tags: meaning, technical-terminology, informal

Ich kann in keinem Wörterbuch das Verb *durchschleifen* finden. Es geht um IT-Umgangssprache. Der Kontext ist:

> Dann müssten wir den Parameter durchschleifen.

Das heißt so was wie durchreichen, übergeben, liege ich richtig?
Ist das Verb trennbar?

Comment: Bitte erst Wörterbücher ausprobieren und dann darstellen, inwiefern diese die Antwort nicht liefern.

Comment: @userunknown habe ich.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ja, die Bedeutung ist "durchreichen", und das Verb ist trennbar.

> Wir schleifen den Parameter durch.

Hingegen empfände ich

> *Wir durchschleifen den Parameter.

so als durchquerte jemand schleifend einen Parameter, was nicht viel Sinn ergibt.

Answer (score 6):

Der Begriff [*Durchschleifen*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchschleifen) in der hier gesuchten Bedeutung kommt ursprünglich aus der Elektrotechnik und wird dort seit langem gebraucht (bei Google Books habe ich ihn in einem [Dokument der AEG](https://books.google.de/books?id=gHnmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22durchschleifen%22+kabel&dq=%22durchschleifen%22+kabel&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5gdjfjtrLAhVFvA8KHcZBB14Q6AEINjAE) von 1937 gefunden). Er bezeichnet eine Verdrahtungsart, bei der die Kabel, die in ein Gerät hineingeführt werden, um es anzuschließen, aus diesem auch wieder herausgeführt werden, um in der Folge weitere Geräte daran anzuschließen. In der Audio- und Videotechnik bezeichnet man so das (Wieder-)Bereitstellen eines Eingangssignals als Ausgangssignal, und von dort führt die Analogie weiter zur IT, wo man so - wie Du richtig vermutest - das unveränderte Weiterreichen eines Aufrufparameters an eine andere Funktion bezeichnet.

Es handelt sich um ein schwaches, trennbares Verb, das noch eine weitere Bedeutung hat: jemanden durchschleppen (mit Mühe und / oder Zwang durch eine Situation hindurchbringen) (Quelle: [DWDS-Wörterbuch](http://www.dwds.de/?view=10&qu=durchschleifen)). Es gibt außerdem das starkes Verb *durchschleifen*, womit das Durchtrennen durch schleifende Bearbeitung (z.B. mit einem Trennschleifer) bezeichnet wird.

Wie es zur Verwendung des Wortes in der Elektrotechnik kam, konnte ich nicht herausfinden. Das Grimmsche Wörterbuch nennt als Bedeutung für *durchschleifen* u.a. (zitiert nach dem DWDS):

- durchkriechen, durch einen engen Ort sich durchwinden
- auf einer Schleife etwas durch einen Ort führen

Beides käme meiner Meinung nach dafür in Frage, in übertragener Bedeutung für die beschriebene Verdrahtungsart benutzt worden zu sein.

Answer (score 4):

Das trennt man durch-schlei-fen. Ist wirklich IT-Umgangssprache. Es ist mehr als übergeben, dabei wird ein Parameter nur an eine Funktion gegeben. Durchschleifen ist mehr, kann über mehrere Programmteile weitergegeben werden. z. B. eine Funktion bekommt den Parameter übergeben, ruft eine andere Funktion auf, die dann auch den Parameter übergeben bekommt. Durchreichen sehe ich als Synonym an.

Man sagt: Der Parameter wird duchgeschleift. Oder: Wir schleifen den Parameter durch.

Comment: Ich denke bei der Frage zur Trennbarkeit, ging es eher darum ob es "Ich schleife den parameter durch" oder "ich durchschleife den Parameter" heißt.

Comment: ich durchschleife den Parameter habe ich noch nie gehört. Üblich: Der Parameter wird duchgeschleift. Oder: Wir schleifen den Parameter durch.

Answer (score 1):

For the rules and different meanings of separable particle verbs (vs inseparable prefix verbs), have a look at my answer here: [Exhaustive list of particles that generate separable verbs](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28317/exhaustive-list-of-particles-that-generate-separable-verbs/28323#28323)

*durchschleifen* is stressed on the non-verb part, therefore it's a particle verb and therefore separable.

And yes, the meaning in your example is *durchreichen*, probably with a negative connotation (we have to, but would be happy if there was any other solution).

Comment: How about *frühstücken*, then?

Comment: @tofro There are some exceptions where particle verbs are not solely built from a particle and a verb but rather built from a noun (which again may come from a verb). *frühstücken* is one of them (comes from *Frühstück*), another would be *uraufführen* (comes from *Uraufführung* which comes from *Aufführung* which comes from *aufführen*). I found an interesting thesis about this here: http://edoc.hu-berlin.de/master/willeke-felix-2006-05-07/PDF/willeke.pdf *durchschleifen*, however, is not built from a noun.