# Durchgeschleift oder durchgeschliffen?

Tags: past-participle

In [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/28792/1696) geht es um die technische Bedeutung des Wortes "durchschleifen". Es herrscht aber offenbar keine Einigkeit darüber, wie das Partizip Perfekt dazu lautet.

Beispiele aus DWDS:

> Da der Druckerport zum Einlesen dient, kann nicht gleichzeitig gedruckt werden, auch wenn der Drucker durchgeschliffen ist. (c't, 1994, Nr. 11)
>
> Im Rahmen der letzten Sozialversicherungsdebatten des scheidenden Bundestages wurde der Mutterschutz als eine der Fransen des zerfledderten Sozialpakets gewissermaßen nebenbei mit durchgeschleift. (Die Zeit, 16.07.1965, Nr. 29)

Heute im Netz:

> Das HDMI-Signal wird dabei durchgeschliffen. ([Heise.de](https://heise.de/-3350009)

Meiner Einschätzung nach taugt *durchgeschliffen* nur im Kontext einer Schleifmaschine, für den technischen Ausdruck müsste es *durchgeschleift* heißen. Dazu müsste man aber nachweisen, dass das das technische *durchschleifen* analog zu *hinter sich her ziehen* konjugiert wird. Geht das?

Comment: Siehe auch: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28792/einen-parameter-durchschleifen

Comment: das starke Verb (*schleifen, schliff, geschliffen*) wirkt hier unangebracht, es sei denn, dass das HDMI-Signal tatsächlich verändert wird. *Geschleift* wäre richtiger, da das Signal wohl wirklich nur *weitergerecht* wird. Wobei ich zuerst die Assoziation mit des Schleifens einer Festung hatte (was irritierender Weise wiederum das schwache Verb verlangt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meiner Ansicht nach kommt die Begrifflichkeit weder vom Schleifstein (also "schärfen") noch vom "Säcke hinter sich herschleifen", sondern am ehesten noch von der Schleife (im Haar).

Eine Schleife ist hier gleichzusetzen mit der Richtung "rein-durch-raus" und das ist genau das, was mit der Variable oder dem Kabel passiert. Die "[Schleife](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schleife_(Programmierung))" als *Programmschleife* ist dem Programmierer ja auch nicht ganz fremd und ein elektrisches Signal kann auch ohne Weiteres in einer Schleife laufen (siehe [Erdschleife](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdschleife)).

Meiner Ansicht nach ist das eine seltene Verb-Neubildung aus einem Substantiv. Natürlich sagt die Herkunft noch überhaupt nichts darüber aus, wie das Partizip gebildet werden muss, da aber alle "neuen" Verben grundsätzlich schwache Verben sind, wird das hier wohl auch so sein.

Damit

> eine Variable wird *durchgeschleift*
>
> ein Signal wurde *durchgeschleift*

Answer (score 8):

Beide Formen sind prinzipiell möglich. Die Vorsilbe »durch« ist dabei unerheblich. Das Verb »schleifen« kann sowohl zu »geschliffen« als auch zu »geschleift« werden:

> Ich habe das Messer **geschliffen**.
>   Ich habe den Sack mit den Paketen zu Post **geschleift**.

Das gibt es auch bei anderen Verben, z.B. »saugen«:

> Ich habe Staub **gesaugt**.
>   Das Baby hat an der Mutterbrust Milch **gesogen**.

In den genannten Beispielen tragen die unterschiedlichen Formen unterschiedliche Bedeutungen, das muss aber nicht sein. Im folgenden Beispiel bedeuten beide Sätze genau dasselbe, hier handelt es sich aber um regionale Unterscheide (»winken«):

> Sonja hat aus dem Fenster **gewinkt**.
>   Sonja hat aus dem Fenster **gewunken**.

Im konkreten Fall (durchschleifen) liegt ein Bedeutungsunterschied vor:

> Markus hat beim Schliefen des dünnen Glases ein Loch hinein gemacht. Es hat das Glas **durchgeschliffen**.
>   Helmut wollte nicht um die Pfütze herum gehen. Er hat den Sack einfach **durchgeschleift**.

In der von dir verwendeten Bedeutung (ein elektrisches Signal unverändert durch ein Bauteil leiten) gehe ich davon aus, dass es nicht von der durch Reibung bewerkstelligten Bearbeitung harter Werkstücke abstammt, sondern davon, dass A durch B durchgezogen wird, wobei A an B reibt. Ich denke, das der Begriff daher kommt, dass man (zumindest der Idee nach) einen Draht durch ein Bauteil durchzieht, was zwangsweise dazu führt, dass der gezogene Draht bei seiner Bewegung durch das Innere des Bauteils am Bauteil reibt.

Insofern halte ich

> <del>Das HDMI-Signal wird dabei durchgeschliffen.</del>

für falsch, während ich

> Das HDMI-Signal wird dabei durchgeschleift.

für richtig halte.